# Azure authentication endpoint over VPN

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

Fishing for ideas here on Azure infrasctructure setup.
My company has on-prem Hadop cluster and Azure Datalake, for connectivity we use http proxy or VPN (no ExpressRoute yet)

We have an ETL application (python, spark) that transfers data from HDFS to ADLS using SPN – python SDK is used to get credentials from login.microsoftonline.com (via proxy) and these are then used for Spark writing files to ADLS gen2 **via private endpoint.**

Now we would like to copy files using hdfs cli (`hdfs dfs -cp hdfs://file abfs://file` .
We found it its working when using Aceess key and connection is going throgh the proxy (=public ADLS endpoint)

It does not work when trying to access the ADLS through private endpoint that is accessible from the on-premise cluster – **because we cannot connect to login.microsoftonline.com without using proxy**. But once the proxy is set, we can only upload data via public ADLS endpoint.

Do you know about anything that could help me resolve the issue?
Only thing that came to my mind was to create internal DNS record that would point to the internet address

Answer (score 0):

1. abfs connector uses java proxy sysprops. so listing the VPN IP/hostname in the https.nonProxyHosts *should* be enough for this to work.
2. recommend using cloudstore's storediag command to do the diagnostics, it's designed to debug auth/connection problems: https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore
3. if you can't get it to work, file a bug report on the apache jira against hadoop, component fs/azure. do test with the latest release first, as "does this work on the latest release" will probably be the first response